# Order by a join table count column using Sequalize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have been trying to get this to work for some time and was hoping for some insight.

GOAL: I am trying to order the posts by the amount of likes they currently have.

CURRENT:

```
const posts = await db.post.findAll({
    include: [ db.user, { model: db.like_post, where: { user_id: user }, required: false } ],
    where: { category },
    group: [ [ sequelize.col('like_posts.post_id') ] ],
    order: [ [ sequelize.fn('count', sequelize.col('like_posts.post_id')), 'DESC' ] ]
});
```

The error I'm getting currently says:

```
"message": "column \"post.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function",
```

Anyone has any advice what I might be doing wrong in order to get the right order of my posts?

Thank again for all the help and tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use an aggregate function `count` all other fields listed between SELECT and FROM should be in listed in GROUP BY.
If you just want to order `post` by a count of related records in `like_post` and keep all fields from `post` along with included from `user` you should use a raw subquery in `order` option.

Something like this:

```
order: [[sequelize.literal('(select count(*) from like_post where like_post.post_id=post.id)', 'DESC']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanation. When I tried the example given I was seeing an error of `"message": "column \"user.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function",` In regards to your comment. I would need to add every column that includes has into group as well? as the the example answer. Since it asks for user.id, should I be joining all the tables for the literal if I took that path? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you go the way I indicated then also remove `group` option.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This was a great learning experience and also the right answer.